# How to get COUNT(*) value from sqlite3_exec()?

Tags: c, sqlite

In my C program I have to check if count of a table in database is one or zero and to do that i am executing query as follows:

```
char *sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=family;";
int table_count = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
printf("\n%d\n", table_count);
```

I'm expecting table_count to be 1 as only one table exists with name family but printf outputs table_count as '21' which is incorrect. How can we get the COUNT(*) value from C/C++ API in C program the right/correct way?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [the SQLite *documentation*](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), because that's not how the [`sqlite3_exec`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) function is supposed to work.

Comment: The third parameter is a callback which gets called with each record in your result set.  Check the duplicate link for sample code.

Comment: And when you can an error back (such as 21), you should call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @CL. Thank you for making me realize that '21' is error code and not the 'table_count' returned for COUNT . I have fixed my code now and if you could please re-open this question, I can post a detailed answer detailing my mistakes and a fixed sample code that outputs COUNT. It might help others who visit this page, just in case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for pointing me to a useful sample on that page.

Comment: @CL. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading SQLite Documentation and following other kind implicit/explicit suggestions in the comments on the question, I have realized my mistakes in that code snippet quoted in the question.

**Mistake 1:** 
I did not implement callback function to receive the result set after the SQL query gets executed. [Have implemented this callback: see *checkTable_Callback* in code below]

**Mistake 2:**
That output of '21' is actually the error code and as per the SQLite documentation that error code corresponds to [SQLite_MISUSE](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#misuse) Which was being generated, perhaps, because I was using a separate function to open my test database file and instance of that opened database, i assume, stayed inside that *openDb* function, and when i used another function *checkTableCount* from where i took that messy snippet to quote in my question, there db instance perhaps was null, hence 21. Experts can elaborate further if that's why i was receiving error code 21. Anyways, now i have fixed that function and made that *openDb* return an opened db instance (better word?) and now 21 error is gone. [see code below]

**Here is fixed and '*adapted-for-my-case*' code**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "sqlite3.h" /* sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.h both reside in
                            my <program_source.c>'s folder */
    static int checkTable_Callback(
                void *unnecessary_here,
                int number_of_columns_in_result_row, /* will always be 1 in this case */
                char **value_of_count, /* will be either 0 or 1 in this case */
                char **label_for_count) { /* will be COUNT(*) normally,
                 but modified via 'AS table_tablename' in this case*/
      printf("COUNT(*) %s\t=>\t%s\n", label_for_count[0], value_of_count[0] );
      return 0;
    } // end of checkTable_Callback()

    char * build_sql(const char *sql_partA, const char *sql_partB) {
      size_t size = strlen(sql_partA) + strlen(sql_partB);
      char *sql_final = malloc(size + 1);
      strcpy(sql_final, sql_partA);
      strcat(sql_final, sql_partB);
      return sql_final;  /* allocated memory to be freed at the end of calling function */
    } // end of build_sql()

    checkTableCount(sqlite3 *db, char *tablename) {
      char *sql  = build_sql(
                      build_sql(
                         build_sql(
                            build_sql(
                            "SELECT COUNT(*) AS table_",
                            tablename),
                      " FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"),
                      tablename),
                   "';");
      sqlite3_exec(db, sql, checkTable_Callback, 0, NULL); 
    /* error checking sacrificed for brevity of sample */
      free(sql);
    }// end of checkTableCount()

    sqlite3 * openDb(char * db_name){
      sqlite3 *db;
      int result_code = sqlite3_open(db_name, &db);
      if( result_code != 0 )
           fprintf(stderr, "\tError: %s\n\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return db;
    } // end of openDb()

    int main() {
      sqlite3 * db = openDb("testing.db"); /* testing.db already has one table 'family'*/
      checkTableCount(db, "family");
      checkTableCount(db, "fam"); /* no such table exist */
      sqlite3_close(db);
      return 0;
    } // end of main()
```

Now this quoted '*adapted-for-my-case*' code rightly and correctly outputs the COUNT(*) as follows:

**OUTPUT**

```
 COUNT(*) table_family   =>      1
 COUNT(*) table_fam      =>      0
```

Note that I didn't bother to write a for-loop inside my callback function named *checkTable_Callback* to iterate through columns as shown in the official sample of callback function [on this page](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) because of the fact that our expected result row is certainly going to be only one containing *only one column* with label modified, via 'AS' clause, into 'table_tablename'. If not modified via 'AS clause', the returned column label would be 'COUNT(*)' in the result row.